# Check if user already exist and wait for callback

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose

I have a small function to validate the user input. In that function I will also check if the email address is already taken. But I have some trouble with the async callback.
I hope anyone could give me a hint, how I could solve this. I use nodejs with the express 3 framework, mongodb and the node-validator library.

This is a part of my validation function:

```
function check(data, callback) {
    mongoose.model('User', User).count(data, function (err, count) {
        callback(err, !! count);
    });
};

function validate(email, password, confirm) {
    var v = new Validator(),
        errors = new Array();

    v.error = function (msg) {
        errors.push(msg);
    };

    check({email: email}, function (err, exists) {
        v.check(exists, { email: 'E-Mail is already taken' }).equals(false);
    });
    ...
    return errors;
}
```

Based on the async callback the variable `errors` is at the `return` statement empty. How could I else check if the email address is already in the databse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think async and pass callbacks that will be called asynchronously.
Quick example:

```
app.get('/blah', function(req, res) {
   // Whatever
   validate(email, pass, confirm, function(errors) {
     if (errors.length == 0)
         resp.send(200, 'blah');
     else
         resp.send(400, 'blah blah');
   });
})

function validate(email, password, confirm, callback) {
    var v = new Validator(),
        errors = new Array();

    v.error = function (msg) {
        errors.push(msg);
    };

    check({email: email}, function (err, exists) {
        v.check(exists, { email: 'E-Mail is already taken' }).equals(false);
    }, function() {
        callback(errors);
    });
    // ...
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: I guess I have to call the second callback after the first in check, right? `function check(data, callback, callback2)`. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Yes, likely, Jacob's answer has an example on the sequencing.

Answer (score 4):

You are going to have to add a callback to your `validate` function.  As it stands now, your `check` function is asynch so you are immediately returning the empty `errors` array.

```
function check(data, callback) {
    mongoose.model('User', User).count(data, function (err, count) {
        callback(err, !! count);
    });
};

function validate(email, password, confirm, callback) {
    var v = new Validator(),
        errors = new Array();

    v.error = function (msg) {
        errors.push(msg);
    };

    check({email: email}, function (err, exists) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        v.check(exists, { email: 'E-Mail is already taken' }).equals(false);
        callback(null, v);
    });
};

// Calling to validate example
server.get("/validate_user_or_whatever", function(req, resp) {
    // Call validate with callback
    validate(req.param("email"), req.param("password"), true, function(err, validator) {
        if (err) {
            return resp.json({success: false, message: err.message});
        }

        var success = validator.isValid; // or something

        // Respond with the results
        resp.json({success: success});
    });
});
```

Now, your next question is probably going to be how do I run all these validate functions and wait for them to return before calling the validate `callback`.  Good question, take a look at the [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async).